# When placing a new .pdf file with the same name on website, in iOS the cached file is downloaded

Tags: html, ios, .htaccess, pdf, caching

In .htaccess i have added a "Header set Cache-control" rule and is working fine (most of it) but in iOS this is not working due to the caching in iOS i think. Is there a solution to force refresh the new pdf files?

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(pdf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, must-revalidate"   
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you show the headers you are setting?

Comment: The easiest way to force refresh is to add a random query parameter to the url, `name.pdf?timestamp=11923819032810`

Comment: this is my header: 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch ".(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Comment: I'd try one of the many "disable caching in all browsers" recipes floating around first. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Comment: How are you downloading the pig ? Thought URLSeesion.dataTask ?

Comment: Thanks. I added a timestamp tot the url. Seems OK now